# Show/Hide multiple divs on image click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm very new to coding, so bear with me. I've looked at a few of the answered posted for the same question, and have gotten the code to work while inputting my information in some of the solved jsfiddle links.

The problem is: When I plug the working code into my HTML and JS file, it doesn't seem to work. I've looked over my code and am not sure what's breaking it or why it's not showing. I was wondering if anyone could look at my code and tell me why?

The section I'm talking about is the Browse Menu and Menu Output sections. Basically, if you click an image (omnivore, vegetarian, healthy) in the browse menu navigation, the corresponding menu output will be shown.

I've also included my HTML and JS to this post. The styles and spacing are a little messed up right now since I've been tinkering with things in my Mark up. I also recently read that tables are bad, so I will be changing that in my html to unordered lists.

Thanks so much!

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Spice Up Your Love Life: An Interactive Dating Experience</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta name="keywords" content="date, interactive, cooking, culinary, dating, couple, love, date ideas, vancouver, spice, love life, experience">
    <meta name="Spice Up Your Love Life" content="SpiceUpYourLoveLife.com is an interactive dating experience in which you and your date can cook a meal together. Eat your heart out!">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="assets/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style2.css">
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Rokkitt:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <style type="text/css">
        @font-face{ 
            font-family: "talldark";
            src: url('http://fontsforweb.com/public/fonts/383/talldark.eot');
            src: local("Tall Dark And Handsome Condensed"), url('http://fontsforweb.com/public/fonts/383/talldark.woff') format("woff"), url('http://fontsforweb.com/public/fonts/383/talldark.ttf') format("truetype");
        }
        .diettitle {
            font-family: "talldark";
            font-size: 6em;
            letter-spacing: 5px;
            color: #b5a839;
        }
        .testerz {
            font-family: "talldark";
            font-size: 1em;
            letter-spacing: 4px;
            color: #b5a839;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<header>
Spice Up Your Love Life: An Interactive Dating Experience
</header>

<div id="topnavcontainer">
    <table id="topnav">
        <tr>
            <td id="break"><a href="google.ca">Breakfast</a></td>
            <td id="lunch"><a href="google.ca">Lunch</a></td>
            <td id="dinner"><a href="google.ca">Dinner</a></td>
            <td id="appetizer"><a href="google.ca">Appetizer</a></td>
            <td id="desert"><a href="google.ca">Desert</a></td>
            <td id="snack"><a href="google.ca">Snack</a></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>


    <table id="mainnav">
        <tr>
            <td id="home" class="bordernav"><a href="google.ca">Home</a></td>
            <td id="works" class="bordernav"><a href=".waves">How It Works</a></td>
            <td id="menu" class="bordernav"><a href="#diet">Menu</a></td>
            <td id="mainnavbordernone"></td>
            <td id="tips" class="bordernav"><a href="google.ca">Tips and Tricks</a></td>
            <td id="contact" class="bordernav"><a href="google.ca">Test Skills</a></td>
            <td id="share" class="bordernav"><a href="google.ca">Share</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td id="logo"><a href="test.html"><img src="images/logo.png" alt="Spice Up Your Love Life Logo" width="189" height="170"></a></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td id="spicetitle" class="title">SPICE</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td id="upyourtitle" class="title">UP  &nbsp;YOUR</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td id="lovelifetitle" class="title">LOVE LIFE</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </table>


    <div class="container">
    <!--SPLASH CONTENT-->
    <div class="content">
    <div id="leftgrid">
    <img src="images/block.jpg" width="300" height="184"><br>
    <p class="contentheader">HOW DOES IT WORK?</p><br>
    <p class="contentdescribed">Does it sound too good to be true? --- Well, it's not!  See how it works and and how it all started. </p>
    <p class="contentcalltoaction"><a href=".waves">See how it works</a></p>
    </div>

    <div id="middleleftgrid">
    <img src="images/block.jpg" width="300" height="184"><br>
    <p class="contentheader">WHAT'S FOR DINNER?</p><br>
    <p class="contentdescribed">Eat your heart out! Browse our menu and select what 
    you'd like to cook for your     special date. </p>
    <p class="contentcalltoaction"><a href="#diet">Look at the menu</a></p>
    </div>

    <div id="middlerightgrid">
    <img src="images/block.jpg" width="300" height="184"><br>
    <p class="contentheader">IMPRESS YOUR DATE!</p><br>
    <p class="contentdescribed">Don't get caught with your elbows on the table! 
    These tips will have them wanting seconds! </p>
    <p class="contentcalltoaction"><a href="google.ca">Learn tips and tricks</a></p>
    </div>

    <div id="rightgrid">
    <img src="images/block.jpg" width="300" height="184"><br>
    <p class="contentheader">GOT WHAT IT TAKES?</p><br>
    <p class="contentdescribed">Put your skills to the test! Take our multiple choice test to see what culinary level you're at!</p>
    <p class="contentcalltoaction"><a href="google.ca">Test your skills</a></p>
    </div>
    </div>


    <!-- HOW IT WORKS SECTION -->
    <div id="howitworkssec">
    <div class="waves"></div>
        <h3 class="headliners"><strong>How does it work?</strong></h3>
        <img src="images/silboth.png" alt="dating silhouette" width="875" height="499"> 
    </div>

    <div id="howdesdiv">
    <p id="simpleas">It's as simple as 1, 2, 3.</p>
    <p id="howdes">
            1. Do this thing and that blah blah<br>
            2. Then you do this lolol can you believez it?<br>
            3. I'll add the actual content when the site is finished.<br>
        </p>
        <a href="#diet" alt="Browse Menu">Let's begin!</a>
    </div>









<!--BROWSE MENU-->
<div id="diet">
 <h3 id="meal" class="headliners">Meal Type</h3>
    <p id="lefty" class="curly">{</p>
    <p id="righty" class="curly">}</p>
<div class="dietchoice"><a href="#meat"><img src="images/carnivoreb.png" alt="meat options" width="90" height="93" /><h3 class="testerz">Omnivore</h3></a></div>
<div class="dietchoice"> <a href="#veggie"><img src="images/vegetarianb.png" alt="meat options" width="90" height="93" /><h3 class="testerz">Vegetarian</h3></a> </div>    
<div class="dietchoice"> <a href="#healthy"><img src="images/healthyb.png" alt="meat options" width="90" height="34" /><h3 class="testerz">Healthy</h3></a> </div>     


<!--MENU OUTPUT-->
<div id="output">
    <div id="meat">
    <p class="diettypeheading">Magnificent Meat Dishes</p>
    <img src="images/centermeatballs.jpg" alt="meatballsplash" width="600" height="400" id="meatleft" >
    <img src="images/centerchicken.jpg" alt="meatballsplash" width="533" height="400" id="meatcenter">
    <img src="images/centersteak.jpg" alt="meatballsplash" width="529" height="400" id="meatright">
    </div>

    <div id="veggie">
    <p class="diettypeheading">Fresh, Colourful Dishes</p>
    <img src="images/centermeatballs.jpg" alt="meatballsplash" width="600" height="400" id="meatleft" >
    <img src="images/meatballs.jpg" alt="meatballsplash" width="533" height="400" id="meatcenter">
    <img src="images/centersteak.jpg" alt="meatballsplash" width="529" height="400" id="meatright">
    </div>      

    <div id="healthy">
    <p class="diettypeheading">Diabetic and Heart Healthy Meals</p>
    <img src="images/centermeatballs.jpg" alt="meatballsplash" width="600" height="400" id="meatleft" >
    <img src="images/centerchicken.jpg" alt="meatballsplash" width="533" height="400" id="meatcenter">
    <img src="images/meatballs.jpg" alt="meatballsplash" width="529" height="400" id="meatright">
    </div>          
</div>



     <!--END OF CONTENT-->  
    <div class="splashimage">
    <img src="images/banner3.png" alt="splash image" width="1664" height="400">
    </div>


    <div id="sitemap">
            <table class="sitemaptab">
  <tr id="sitemaptitles">
    <th>Get Social</th>
    <th>Quick Links</th>
    <th>Terms of Use</th>
  </tr>
    <tr id="row_two">
    <td class="social"><a href="twitter.com"><img src="images/socialmedia/twit_sm.png" alt="sm-twiticon">Follow Us On Twitter</a></td>
    <td class="quicklinks"><a href="#topnavcontainer">Home</a></td>
    <td class="terms"><a href="google.ca">Privacy Policy</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="row_three">
    <td class="social"><a href="facebook.com"><img src="images/socialmedia/fb_sm.png" alt="sm-fbicon">Like Us On Facebook</a></td>
    <td class="quicklinks"><a href="#menudiv">Browse Menu</a></td>
    <td class="terms"><a href="google.ca">Contact</a></td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td> </td>
    <td class="quicklinks"><a href=".waves">How It Works</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td class="quicklinks"><a href="google.ca">Tips and Tricks</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td class="quicklinks"><a href="google.ca">Share</a></td>
  </tr>
</table>
    </div>






<footer>
    <table id="footer">
        <tr>
            <td id="copyright">Copyright © Spice Up Your Love Life 2013</td>
            <td id="webdesby">Web Design By: <a href="http://google.ca">Ticking and Talking Media</a></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</footer>
<script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/spicelovelife.js"></script>
<script src="js/plugins.js"></script>
<script src="js/vendor/jquery-1.9.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/vendor/modernizr-2.6.2.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

JavaScript:

```
// Scrolling Function
$('a').click(function(){
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $( $(this).attr('href') ).offset().top
    }, 500);
    return false;
});

// Load All Images
$('body').waitForImages({
    waitForAll: true,
    finished: function() {
       // All images have loaded.
    }  
});


//Hide All Divs
$("#output > div").hide();

$(".dietchoice a").click(function(e) {
  $("#output div").hide();
  $(this.hash).show();
  e.preventDefault();
});
$("#areas div:not(#meat)").hide();
```

Comment: can u create link for  rthis

Comment: Sorry, totally new to this. Do you mean a link to the webpage?

Comment: i did not understand your problem.Can u explain clearly

Comment: Are the `<div>`'s not hiding?  Not showing?  What is the problem you're seeing?

Comment: would you make a working example on [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit).

Comment: Sorry if I didn't explain properly. The divs in the Menu Output are not hiding. What I want is when I click one of the imgs in the Browse Menu section, that the correct div will show. Upon clicking another img in the Browse Menu section, the current div will hide and the new one will show.

here is the plunker link: http://plnkr.co/edit/MT4zCZsN3UAzqhvr1yLA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of

```
$(this.hash).show();
```

You should probably use

```
$(this.attr('href')).show();
```

`this.hash` probably returns undefined because the property `hash` doesn't exist.

If my solution throws an error like "undefined method attr()" you will probably need to use the jQuery selector.

```
$($(this).attr('href')).show();
```

I'd advise using the console object for debugging purpose. You can find some docs about debugging on the [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Debugging_JavaScript).

This selector `$("#output > div")` is different from this selector `$("#output div")`. According to your HTML, both selectors returns the same elements but if you were to change the HTML structure issues might arise.

Comment: Hey Thomas! Thanks for answering my question. I've changed the code to "$($(this).attr('href')).show();" as you suggested, but the problem still exists. 

I've tried the JavaScript console in Chrome and the only problem I get is: 
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'waitForImages'  "

Thanks for the resource!

Comment: Well, that's your first problem, you have to solve this error otherwise the rest of the code won't be initialized. At the time `waitForImages` is called it doesn't exist. Make sure your javascript files are ordered properly and you wrap your code in the [ready event](http://api.jquery.com/ready/). For now, you should comment out that part out and let me know if it works.

Comment: You sir, are a GOD. Thank you very very much! I've been stuck on this for two days hahaha. 'waitForImages' is from a code I found for preloading all the images on the page. It must have been dated or incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

try, putting the modernizr, jquery and plugin scripts before your code, meaning change this:

```
<script src="spicelovelife.js"></script>
<script src="js/plugins.js"></script>
<script src="js/vendor/jquery-1.9.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/vendor/modernizr-2.6.2.min.js"></script>
```

to this:

```
<script src="js/vendor/jquery-1.9.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/plugins.js"></script>
<script src="js/vendor/modernizr-2.6.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/spicelovelife.js"></script>
```

Hope this help.

Comment: This is great! Thanks for helping =) I was afraid of coming on these boards cause I thought people would pick on my n00byness. You guys are real helpful!